# Synchronous NodeJs (or other serverside JS) call

Tags: node.js

We are using Node for developing and 95% of code is Async, working fine.

For some 5% (one small module), which is sync in nature [and depends on other third party software],

and we are looking for 
1. "Code to block until call back is finished" 
2. At a time only one instance of function1 + its callback should be executed.

PS 1: I do completely agree, Node is for async work, We should avoid that, but this is separate non-realtime process.

PS 2: If not with Node any other Serverside JS framework?  Last option is to use other lang like python, but if anything in JS possible, we are ready to give it a shot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SEQ](https://github.com/substack/node-seq) should solve your problem.

For an overview about sync modules please look at http://nodejsrocks.blogspot.de/2012/05/how-to-avoid-nodejs-spaghetti-code-with.html

```
Seq()
 .seq(function () {
   mysql.query("select * from foo",[], function(err,rows,fields) {

        this(null, rows);
   });
 })
 .seq(function(mysqlResult) {
     console.log("mysql callback returnes:"+mysqlResult);
 })
```

Comment: SEQ waits until last callback calls SEQ.this(err, params)  

Seq()
    .seq(function () {
       mysql.query("select * from foo",[], function(err,rows,fields) {

            this(null, rows);
    })

Answer (score 0):

There are lots and lots of options, look at [node-async](https://github.com/caolan/async), [kaffeine](http://weepy.github.com/kaffeine/docs/unwrapping_async_calls.html) async support, [IcedCoffeescript](http://maxtaco.github.com/coffee-script/), etc.

Comment: i tried async.series, but it is not waiting for callback. Any small ex. will be of much help!

Answer (score 0):

I want to make a plug for [IcedCoffeeScript](http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script) since I'm its maintainer.  You can get by with solutions like Seq, but in general you'll wind up encoding control flow with function calls. I find that approach difficult to write and maintain. IcedCoffeeScript makes simple sequential operations a breeze:

```
console.log "hello, just wait a sec"
await setTimeout defer(), 100
console.log "ok, what did you want"
```

But more important, it handles any combination of async code and standard control flow:

```
console.log "Let me check..."
if isRunningLate()
  console.log "Can't stop now, sorry!"
else
  await setTimeout defer(), 1000
  console.log "happy to wait, now what did you want?"
resumeWhatIWasDoingBefore()
```

Also loops work well, here is serial dispatch:

```
for i in [0...10]
   await launchRpc defer res[i]
done()
```

And here is parallel dispatch:

```
await
   for i in [0...10]
      launchRpc defer res[i]
done()
```

Not only does ICS make sequential chains of async code smoother, it also encourages you to do as much as possible in parallel.  If you need to change your code or your concurrency requirements, the changes are minimal, not a complete rewrite (as it would be in standard JS/CS or with some concurrency libraries).